# Wrong values returned from cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

It look like complete paranormal activity to me. I got this little function converting database data into objects:

```
public List<BudgetSummary> getMonnthlyBalance() {
    List<BudgetSummary> list = new ArrayList<BudgetSummary>();

    DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(context);
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = db.open();
    MonthlyBalanceSqlSelect sql = new MonthlyBalanceSqlSelect();
    Cursor cursor = sql.getCursor(sqldb);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(new BudgetSummary(cursor));
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

`MonthlyBalanceSqlSelect` contains sql query, which I copied from the debugger to the Sqliteman. I have extracted database file from the app. Here are the results:

[image]

This looks perfect to me. Lets take a look at `BudgetSummary` constructor now. It's simple as wire.

```
public BudgetSummary(Cursor cursor) {
    incomes = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("incomes"));
    expenses = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("expenses"));     
}
```

I was step debugging with every iteration inside this constructor. It should correspond to the data presented on the picture but it doesn't...Here are results:

```
 1. incomes: 4732.0 - wrong   | expenses: -57.59 - wrong     | month and year correct
 2. incomes: 4657.0 - correct | expenses: -3714.96 - correct | month and year correct
 3. incomes: 708.0 - wrong    | expenses: -3383.03 - correct | month and year correct
 4. incomes: 5669.48 - wrong  | expenses: -5669.48 - wrong   | month and year correct
 5. incomes: 3278.5 - correct | expenses: -2685.91 - wrong   | month and year correct
 6. incomes: 4612.5 - wrong   | expenses: -2786.78 - wrong   | month and year correct
 and so on...
```

What sorcery is this? I really don't know... how some values could be correct and the others completly out of the blue?

**Here is the SQL query. I strongly suspect that java sees it different way that Sqliteman accordting to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916210/cursor-returns-wrong-values-sqlite-android?rq=1). Unfortunately I don't know how it should look.**

```
select strftime('%m', b.date) as month , strftime('%Y', b.date) as year, total(case when b.value >= 0 then b.value else 0 end) as incomes, total(case when b.value < 0 then b.value else 0 end) as expenses from budget b, category c where b.category_id = c.id group by month, year order by year desc, month desc
```

Comment: Show us the SQL query.

Comment: Also, storing amounts of money as floating-point is a very bad idea!

Comment: how would you store them?

Comment: @GrahamBorland: It's fine to use a floating point type. It's a bad idea to use a floating *binary* point type. Floating *decimal* point is reasonably suitable.

Comment: Integers, with a separate record of the number of decimal places for display/export

Comment: It sounds crazy. I store them in the database under DOUBLE

Comment: Please show some sample records that illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I *strongly* suspect that the problem is you're assuming the same row ordering in Sqliteman and the Java code. Unless your SQL explicitly specifies the order, you shouldn't assume that it'll be the same. I suggest you include the month and year in your query, and include that in your `BudgetSummary` as well, at least for diagnostics.

Comment: I removed month and year for simplicyty. The go in the order from the picture. And values doesn't match. What's more. The values which doesn't match are not even in any field of this cursor!